# Where can one post proofs of unsolved maths problems? With certifucates etc.

Tags: number-theory

There is a 0.1% chance I have solved an unimportant yet unsolved maths problems.  I live in the UK - can get to London. Where can I get certificate etc if I do solve it. I'm going to talk to my maths teacher (PHD). And If on the extremely rare chance I solve it where do I go?

Comment: You simply send your proof to any maths monthly. Or if a prize is assigned to the problem solver, you email your proof to the organisation.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/i-believe-i-have-solved-a-famous-open-problem-how-do-i-convince-people-in-the-f

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you are acquainted enough with mathematics, you should be able to write a clean proof. Learn LaTeX, write your proof in LaTeX, publish it on [Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/). On this way, you don't have to go by some mathematics professor who may be in dire need of an important publication and it costs no money. If however Arxiv doesn't accept your proof it will be because it is either because your proof is obviously not based on real mathematics or obviously wrong (or you are unable to use LaTeX properly). If Arxiv accepts, soon you will see a thread here or on math overflow on your approach if the problem is really important and your approach seems reasonable enough.

Of course, this isn't THE way to go, just the way I would do it. Technically I think, as Mathmo123 mentioned, this question would be better handled in Academia.

Comment: Thanks -I'm going to ask my maths teacher about it first.

Comment: I would like to know for which reasons my answer doesn't seem to be appropriate (downvotes), so I can improve my answers in the future. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I up-voted your answer